# Serialize LocalDate as TimeStamp using Spring Boot 2.3.4.RELEASE Jackson2ObjectMapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson-databind, localdate

I tried several ways to change the default jackson configuration within the spring boot and it doesn't work.
it simply ignores all configuration

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AvaliacaoairtonApplication {

public static final String URL = "*";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AvaliacaoairtonApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder.build();

    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

    JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
    javaTimeModule.addSerializer(LocalDate.class, new StdScalarSerializer<LocalDate>(LocalDate.class) {

        @Override
        public void serialize(LocalDate localDate, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
                              SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {

            jsonGenerator.writeString(localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")));
        }
    });

    objectMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);

    return objectMapper;
}
```

}

application.properties
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false

POM

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>br.com.softplan</groupId>
<artifactId>avaliacaoairton</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>avaliacaoairton</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQpC4.png)

Comment: Register this one more, `.registerModule(new JSR310Module());`

Comment: @JonathanJOhx, this is deprecated, it's better to use this -- `.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());`